# Правильный вывод дочернего меню (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, в общем нужно чтобы дочернее меню выводилось при ховере на ссылку, а не на элемент `li`, проблема в том что дочернее меню является дочерним для `li` а не для `a` и поэтому при попытке допустим выборку сделать не через `.children()` а `.next()` при потере `.hover` у `a` дочернее меню схлопывается, как добиться, чтобы такое происходило только при наведении на ссылку вне дочернего меню? Надеюсь понятно объяснил.
Пример:

```js
$(".product-categories > li > a").hover(function() {
  var child = $(this).next('.children');
  if ($(child).css('display') === 'none') {
    $(child).slideDown("fast", function() {});
  } else {
    $(child).slideUp("fast", function() {});
  }
});
```

```css
.children{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-categories">
  <li>
    <a>Девочки
      </a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li>
        <a>Красивые
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Люба</a></li>
          <li><a>Зинаида</a></li>
          <li><a>Валентина Васильевна</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Страшные
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Мальчики
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Дети
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Немного подправил пример, щас думаю станет понятно, навожу на "Девочки" > раскрывается меню, убираю фокус на элементы подменю> схлопывается - такого не должно происходить.

Comment: Ссылка у тебя внутри, как она должна выводиться при его ховере  или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: @Air т.е. я навожу на `a` у первого пункта, далее раскрывается подменю, после того как я навожу мышкой на `a` у подменю - подменю схлопывается, мне нужно чтобы это происходило только если я навожу на `a` другого пункта, либо вообще убираю фокус с меню

Comment: @Air я не знаю, может криво отображается, но по идее подменю скрыто изначально, я навожу на Пункт 1 > раскрывается подменю > я вожу мышкой по Подпунктам (в том числе по подпунктам подпункта) и подменю не должно схлопываться, т.е. как это работает если бы вместо `.next()` написать `children()`, но мне это не подходит

Comment: Извини, давай я тебе в примере кое что изменю, а ты на основе опиши вопрос,  чтобы глаза не прыгали)))  Ты уж не ругайся))

Comment: Объясни в вопросе что да как))) так будет понятнее

Comment: @ВладВолков, а что я там неприличного написал?)))

Comment: А то у меня от этих ПУНКТОВ, ПОДПУНКТОВ, ПОДПУНКТОВ- ПОДПУНКТОВ, глаза в кучу собрались...

Comment: @Денис, здесь можно и нужно обойтись без js. Оберните то, что внутри  li в div'ы. Спозиционируйте эти div'ы как ссылки, и показывайте дочерние списки при наведении на div.

Comment: @Денис, я вот только хотел написать, а что JQ принципиально или главное реализация?

Comment: @Air, убрал. прошу прощения...

Comment: @ВладВолков, поехали, ты не писал, я не читал....

Comment: @Air принципиально, меню формирует cms, лезть в реализацию особого желания нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оно?

```js
let cat = '.product-categories > li > a';

$(cat).hover(function() {
  let child = $(this).next('.children');  
  
  if ($(child).css('display') === 'none') {
    $(cat).next('.children').slideUp("fast");
    $(child).slideDown("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
.children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-categories">
  <li>
    <a>Девочки
      </a>
      <ul class="children">
        <li>
          <a>Красивые
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Люба</a></li>
            <li><a>Зинаида</a></li>
            <li><a>Валентина Васильевна</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Страшные
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Мальчики
      </a>
      <ul class="children">
        <li>
          <a>Дрищёвые
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Леопольд</a></li>
            <li><a>Владлен</a></li>
            <li><a>Матвей</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Страшные
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Дети
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Еще надо чтобы подменю схлопывалось когда на другие пункты наводишь, а у тебя схлопывается когда другое разворачивается, так скажем, а вообще да, то что нужно, спасибо)

Comment: `Еще надо чтобы подменю схлопывалось когда на другие пункты наводишь, а у тебя схлопывается когда другое разворачивается` - разве это не одно и то же?.......... а, кажется понял. Надо было сразу так написать вопрос, кмк.

Comment: Нет, нужно еще `else` добавить, ведь если у пункта нет подменю, то данный пример не схлопывает его в принципе